# Layout and constraint based drawing iOS with and without autolayout

Tags: ios, uiview, constraints, ios-autolayout

Where can I find cleaner example and understanding of following methods.
How they work, who call them and when ? and what is call stack.

```
func systemLayoutSizeFitting(_ targetSize: CGSize, withHorizontalFittingPriority horizontalFittingPriority: UILayoutPriority, verticalFittingPriority: UILayoutPriority) -> CGSize

func systemLayoutSizeFitting(_ targetSize: CGSize) -> CGSize

func setNeedsLayout()
func layoutIfNeeded()
func layoutSubviews()

func setNeedsUpdateConstraints()
func updateConstraintsIfNeeded()
func updateConstraints()

var intrinsicContentSize
func invalidateIntrinsicContentSize()
```

I have tried to understand documentation on [https://developer.apple.com/documentation/](https://docs.apple.com), but could not understand all cases. Can some one provide me example or well written documentation?

Comment: Constraints and autolayout go together; autolayout uses constraints to perform layout. You cannot have autolayout without constraints and if you have constraints then you are using autolayout.

Comment: That I know, but I need above methods if I render my view programatically. How these method communicates with iOS that is my major question.